# Derivative Block Diagrams

Tags: control

I am a newbie in Control Theory. I am solving an exercise found on-line. I do not expect anyone to solve it for me. I would just ask for a clarification about the block "p+a". I suppose it represents a derivative operator, with the input being "-theta". What is the output? The "a" term confuses me.
Thanks in advance.

[image]dealingHow should a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The "a" term confuses me.

A is the proportional gain of the controller.

Actually, a proportional controller is the most basic feedback controller. The output ($u$ in the diagram) is just: $$ u=  Kp \cdot error = Kp ( \theta_{desired} - \theta_{measured} ) $$ In your case, $\theta_{desired} = 0, \ \theta_{measured} = \theta, \ Kp= a$. (But usually the notation used is $Kp$ or $P$, not $a$)

> What is the output?

The controller in the exercise is a PD controller, that is a proportional ( $a$ term) - derivative ($1\cdot p$ term) controller, where the output/command is:
$$ u=  Kp \cdot error + Kd \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(error) $$
In your case, $ \ Kp= a, Kd = 1$.

You can find out more information, searching for a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) controller.

**Extra** I would suggest you pick a book if you want to learn control theory, like [nise](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Control+Systems+Engineering%2C+8th+Edition-p-9781119474227) or [ogata](http://docs.znu.ac.ir/members/pirmohamadi_ali/Control/Katsuhiko%20Ogata%20_%20Modern%20Control%20Engineering%205th%20Edition.pdf) (Ogata is actually a pdf). Not only will the information be presented in a structured manner, but also the notation will be more modern. (I have never seen $p$ used as a symbol for the laplace complex variable, usually $s$ is used. Also, the gains are either $Kp,Kd,Ki$ or $P,D,I$) And reading material with the common notation will help you understand other sources you find online.